# Mostrar selección de ComboBox en una Label en WindowsForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, combobox

Estoy haciendo una app en C# WindowsForms y necesito saber cómo crear una  `label` a partir del ítem seleccionado en el `combobox`. Por ejemplo, si selecciono `hola`en el `combobox` que se cree una label con esa selección. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vamos a crear un control `ComboBox` el cual designaremos como `CBox1` y una función para el control en forma de evento llamado `SelectedIndexChanged` tal cual expreso abajo.

```
    private void CBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

> Crearemos un label en el form y lo iniciaron con la visibilidad en false, lo llamaremos `lbl_ItemSeleccionado`, luego crearemos una función para la edición del texto del `label` con un parametro que sera el texto del item seleccionado en el `ComboBox`

```
    void FormarLabel(string _Texto)
    {
      //Indicamos que trabajaremos con la propiedad .Text del label y le asignamos el parametro de tipo string _Texto
      lbl_ItemSeleccionado.Text = _Texto;
      //Ahora que ya tendrá un texto le asignamos que este visible.
      lbl_ItemSeleccionado.Visible = true;
    }
```

> Y ahora el codigo que se alojara dentro del evento `SelectedIndexChanged` sera una llamada a la funcion que cambia el texto del label.

```
private void CBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      FormarLabel(Cbox1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: En `lbl_ItemSelecionado = _Texto` me dice que no se puede convertir implícitamente string en System.Windows.Forms.Label, y en `FormarLabel(Cbox1.SelectedItem)`me dice que no se puede convertir de object a string.

Comment: Te pido disculpas, cuando llamas al control `label` debemos especificar con que propiedad queremos trabajar en este caso solo basta con ponerle `lbl_ItemSelecionado.Text = _Texto` que lo que hace es trabajar con la propiedad del texto como si lo haríamos manualmente desde las propiedades en el are [Design] del form. ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: No hay problema, suele pasar. Lo que no sé es cómo se crea esa `label`, por que la idea es que, cada vez que se seleccione un ítem en el `combobox`, se vayan creando una al lado de la otra.

Comment: Haz lo siguiente, publica una nueva pregunta con tus hallazgos, codigo, y fuentes de donde sacaste la informacion y la logica que crees conveniente para hacerlo asi te podemos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si el label ya está creado bastará con que en el evento donde quieras gestionar el cambio añadas la siguiente linea de código `this.label.Text = this.comboBox.Text;`

Si deseas crear el label deberás configurarlo manualmente:

```
Label l = new Label();
l.Text= this.comboBox1.Text;
l.Location = new Point(13, 13); //La posición donde quieras colocarlo
this.Controls.Add(l);
```